# Posting image with django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a simple api for marine vessels and ships and I am using django-rest-framework as the library to generate the api. With models that has simple fields like char fields and integers in the models level everything is working properly (create, delete, update, list, get).

The problem is with image fields whenever I try to post a record that has images it does not detect it. And it always causes an error "sequence item 1: expected string, NoneType found"

Below is my model, serializer, and view files.
serializer

```
class VesselSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='image')
    class Meta:
        model = Vessel
        fields = ('image', 'id', 'vesselType', 'name')

class VesselTypeSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VesselType
```

models

```
def vessel_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['vessels', instance.id, filename]) #the error is in this line

class VesselType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)    

class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vesselType = models.ForeignKey(VesselType)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=vessel_file_name, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

views

```
class VesselList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Vessel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VesselSerializer
    fields = ('url', 'id', 'image', 'vesselType')

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print 'entered here'
        print '%' * 10
        print request.DATA
        print request.FILES
        print '%' * 10
        serializer = VesselSerializer(data=request.DATA, files=request.FILES)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class VesselDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Vessel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VesselSerializer
```

It should be noted as well that the request.FILES and request.DATA when printed are displayed correctly yet that error appears which indicates that there is no file name although the name appears in request.FILES.

I am stuck in this problem for several hours and I can't seem to find what the problem is or what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `vessel_file_name` is called, the `instance` object is not saved to the db and `instance.id` is `None`.

Comment: It is clear from the debugging process that's the problem the question I am trying to answer is why so? Everything seems to be in order and yet it doesn't save for some reason, any thoughts on how I might debug the problem?

Comment: From the documentation for `FileField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) _In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field._ So my advice is: don't use `instance.id` in the file path.